# Document scanner Panasonic KV-N1058X: Wrong image height

Tags: scanner, dpi, aspect-ratio, document-scanning

It was one of my bigger mistakes that I bought a Panasonic KV-N1058X a few months ago. I am having all sorts of problems with it, but yesterday I noticed something that stopped me immediately from using it further:

It shrinks all images by a certain factor along the height axis. I am living in Europe where written materials mostly are of DIN A4 size, which is 210 mm x 297 mm. The scanner is configured for 600 dpi, so this would mean 4961 pixels x 7015 pixels.

I have taken a sheet of DIN A4 paper and have verified that it was perfectly rectangular and had exactly the dimensions mentioned above. Then I configured the scanner to DIN A4 *without* automatic crop, and configured the background color to black. Then I let it scan that paper sheet.

The result shocked me. The image the scanner produced was exactly as wide and as high as expected (4961 pixel x 7015 pixels). But it contained a massive black bar at the lower end. The contents of the scanned sheet of paper were all there from the very top to the very bottom and from the very left to the very right. Furthermore, the image of the scanned paper was scaled correctly in the horizontal direction, and there were no black bars at the left or the right side.

However, the image of the scanned paper was incorrectly scaled in the vertical direction. As described above, the actual contents took only about 6700 pixels in height. The rest of the canvas was filled by the horizontal black bar which was about 315 pixels high.

I then have turned on automatic cropping. As expected, when scanning the same sheet of paper, this produced an image with the same correct width, but the image now was only about 6700 pixels high in whole. That is, the black bar was eliminated, but the image still was shrunk in height.

This means that this scanner produces a whopping mistake in the aspect ratio. Of course, I have noticed this after having scanned 2000 pages of documents and destroying the physical copies. Great.

Does anybody know whether it is possible to solve that problem at the scanner side?

My own ideas would be:

- After scanning, in the metadata of the image, leave the horizontal dpi at 600, but slightly reduce the vertical dpi to compensate the scaling. This does not alter the image data and eventually could make the image appear correctly again on printers (if printing it again) and monitors (if the displaying software takes the dpi into account at all).
- After scanning, scale the image accordingly in GIMP or a similar application. However, that would alter the image data and lead to a loss of quality.

What I have done so far to solve the problem myself (without avail):

- I have put a whole day in the issue, trying the TWAIN driver as well as the native scan software (Image Capture Plus), in both cases trying nearly all combination of options that could be related to the problem. The TWAIN driver and the native scan application both produced the same, wrong images.

Comment: What happens if you tell it the page is say 12" or 13" long (or the "legal" pages size of 8.5x14") instead of the standard page size?  Does the black bar move down further?  Maybe try VueScan, although it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: If I tell the scanner that the page is longer, and if I disable autocrop again, the black bar becomes higher, while the part of the image that contains the scanned sheet of paper is at the same size. It seems that the image canvas always is of correct size (provided autocrop is turned off), but that the actual image gets shrinked vertically during the scan.